# Are iOS, Android, Windows 10 mobile emulators available for developing Xamarin.Forms with Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, android, ios, windows, xamarin.forms

I am a newbie in Xamarin.Forms but familiar enough with Visual Studio and c#.
I want to start learning Xamarin.Forms with Visual Studio 2015 under Windows 10. I have iOS and Android smartphones but I think it will be better if I use emulators during the development phases.

My question is

> Are iOS, Android, Windows 10 mobile emulators available for developing Xamarin.Forms with Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, once you setup the environment for developing with Xamarin in Visual Studio you'll have emulators available for Android and Windows 10.
A bunch of emulators is also available from the Android SDK which is installed with Xamarin. The Android emulators from Visual Studio are faster though.
iOS emulators are available on the Mac/XCode which you will need for compiling the Xamarin App for iOS anyway.

Comment: There is no iOS emulator running on Windows?

Comment: No. Unfortunately that's not possible for legal reasons. Apple is very restrictive. Xamarin has announced (or already introduced?) a feature for making the emulator window appear on Windows but the emulator code is still running on the Mac.

Comment: Oh, it is too bad. Thanks.